How to delete migrated records from source table using DMS
I am currently migrating selected records from sql database to s3 bucket (parquet format) using aws DMS. I wanted to delete migrated records in source database after successful creation of paqrquet file in s3. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

This is probably a better fit on [DBA.se]
